# BITCOIN RPC : Failed to connect to localhost port 8332: Connection refused

Tags: php, bitcoin

I can not do a simple easybitcoin command.

Here is my sript :

```
require_once("../Easy_btc/easybitcoin.php");

$bitcoin = new Bitcoin("pseudo","password");
$result = $bitcoin->getinfo();
var_dump($bitcoin);
```

I already included the conf file using bitcoind -conf=conf_path

bitcoin.conf :

```
server = 1 
rpcuser=username 
rpcpasword = password
```

By the way,it worked on my ubuntu system but it doesn't on Windows 10

Comment: (Can you "telnet" to that port?)

Comment: telnet localhost 8332
Connexion à localhost...Impossible d’ouvrir une connexion à l’hôte, sur le port 8332: Échec lors de la connexion

Comment: (French is even more non-native to me than English.) That would suggest that _bitcoind_ isn't running (properly). If it is, please include the `bitcoin.conf file` (and other information that might be helpful) in the question.

Comment: haha sorry I didn't pay attention.

Comment: I already included the conf file using bitcoind -conf=conf_path

Comment: bitcoin.conf :  server = 1 rpcuser=username rpcpasword = password